# Using Horizontal Pod Autoscaling along with resource requests and limits

Tags: kubernetes, horizontal-scaling

Say we have the following deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: ...
          ...
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 50Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 300Mi
```

And we also create a `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` object which automatically scales up/down the number of pods based on CPU average utilization. I know that the HPA will compute the number of pods based on the resource **requests**, but what if I want the containers to be able to request more resources before scaling horizontally?

I have two questions:

1) Are resource **limits** even used by K8s when a HPA is defined?

2) Can I tell the HPA to scale based on resource **limits** rather than requests? Or as a means of implementing such a control, can I set the `targetUtilization` value to be more than 100%?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, HPA is not looking at limits at all. You can specify target utilization to any value even higher than 100%.

Comment: But surely the utilization is a (perhaps indirect) function of one or the other requests/limits?

Comment: There is a factor to keep in mind when using a target utilization much higher than 100% to cause scaling to happen between the CPU request value and the CPU limit value. If the app is installed in a crunched overbooked infrastructure, and your app is at one pod, it may be being throttled, all the way down to its request value.  In short, it may never reach (say) 120% utilization, and if it cannot, it will never scale to 2 pods or higher.

Comment: And even if it does, the scaling may be sluggish, with the sluggishness increasing on apps with higher disparity between CPU request/limit.  Example: request: 500m limit: 1500m, target utilization: 200%

Answer (score 6):

Hi in deployment we have resources **requests and limits**. As per documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#how-pods-with-resource-limits-are-run) those parameters acts before HPA gets main role as autoscaler:

> 1. **When you create a Pod**, the Kubernetes scheduler selects a node for
>      the Pod to run on. **Each node** has a maximum capacity **for each of the
>      resource types: the amount of CPU and memory** it can provide for
>      Pods.
> 2. Then the **kubelet** starts a Container of a Pod, **it passes the CPU and memory limits** to the container runtime.
> 3. If a **Container exceeds** its memory limit, it might be **terminated**. If it is restartable, the kubelet will restart it, as with any other type of runtime failure.

If a Container exceeds its memory request, it is likely that its Pod will be evicted whenever the node runs out of memory.

On the other hand:

> The Horizontal Pod Autoscaler is implemented as a control loop, with a period controlled by the controller manager’s (with default value of 15 seconds).
>   The controller manager queries the resource utilization against the metrics specified in each HorizontalPodAutoscaler definition.

Note:
Please note that if some of the pod’s containers do not have the relevant resource request set, CPU utilization for the pod will not be defined and the autoscaler will not take any action for that metric.

Hope this help