# Does Kubernetes HPA scale on 'limits' or 'requests'

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling, hpa

I am trying to implement the HPA, but I am struggling to understand if the HPA checks the avg cpu utilization of the 'limits' or the 'requests'.

I've defined the following resources:

```
django:
  limits:
    cpu: 400m
    memory: 700Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 200m
    memory: 350Mi
```

on the HPA I configured the following CPU Utilization
`targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 35`

Does this mean 35% of the **requests** 200m (scale up on > 70m) or 35% of the **limits** 400m (scale up on > 140m)

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56198941/using-horizontal-pod-autoscaling-along-with-resource-requests-and-limits ?